# Deny direct visit to path files, but allow visitors from site to access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am looking to block direct access to

`tv.domain.com/file1.php`
or
`tv domain.com/file2.php`

but allow access to `file1.php` if the user/visitors come from `tv.domain.com` ONLY

There are file1 to file25 with same name file + a numeric number 1-25 (file25.php)

How can i do it using `.htaccess`? Thanks!

Comment: Other than relying on the - unreliable - referrer, there is not really a way to do this using .htaccess. You should use a session for this - set a flag when the user visits the root path, and then inside the other files check if that session flag is set first, and if not, either redirect to the root, or respond with a 403 forbidden (whatever exact behavior you need.)

Comment: @CBroe that is a good idea, how do i implement something like that? Thanks

Comment: If you don't know how sessions work in PHP, you should find yourself a tutorial that explains the basics. And then, you simply implement what I said - in the index page, set a flag, and in all other pages that should be "protected" this way, checkif that flag is set in the session first. If not, respond with a 403 status code and let the script `die()` after that, or something similar.